# Reading shape files : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, unicodedecodeerror

I am trying to read shapefiles. I have handled the error that could occur when reading a shapefile by writing a function  `read_gdf` (see code below) but I am still getting an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't...`

```
from pathlib import Path

def read_gdf(file:str,crs:str,current_crs:str)->gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    #Read data
    collection = list(fiona.open(file,'r'))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(collection)

    
    df1['isvalid'] = df1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isvalid(x))
    df1 = df1[df1['isvalid'] == 1]
    collection = json.loads(df1.to_json(orient='records'))

    #Convert to geodataframe
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(collection, crs=current_crs).to_crs(crs)

gdfs = []
for file in Path(rootdir).rglob("*.shp"):
    print('file is', file)            
    gdf = read_gdf(file, crs,current_crs=current_crs)
    gdf.columns = map(str.lower, gdf.columns)                
    gdfs.append(gdf)
```

How can I ignore the line that has the error and continue reading the rest of the shapefile?

Comment: are you sure the Shapefile (or infact dbf) is in UTF-8, if it isn't then you'll need to tell the reader

Comment: When I try `encoding=”iso-8859-1”`  i manage to read the shape file. However, will this encoding damage the reading of the geometry? Why does it not work with the default encoding which is `UTF-8`? what is the difference between `UTF-8` and `”iso-8859-1”`

Comment: The encoding only applies to the attributes of the features not the geometry which are binary. As for the difference between the two one is a standard and the other is used by Microsoft ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. As long as the geometry is not impacted then I am happy

Answer (score 2):

To solve the issue, change the encoding to `encoding='iso-8859-1'`

```
def read_gdf(file:str,crs:str,current_crs:str)->gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    #Read data
    collection = list(fiona.open(file,'r',  encoding='iso-8859-1'))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(collection)

    
    df1['isvalid'] = df1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isvalid(x))
    df1 = df1[df1['isvalid'] == 1]
    collection = json.loads(df1.to_json(orient='records'))

    return gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(collection, crs=current_crs).to_crs(crs)
```

Comment: Accept your own answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Try directly using GeoPandas, without Fiona (GeoPandas use Fiona) and Pandas.

```
import geopandas as gpd
for file in pathlib.Path(directory).rglob('**/*.shp'):
     print('file is', file)   
     # open the shapefile
     try:
        df1 = gpd.read_file(file)
        # all changes in df1
     except:
        print("error")
```

Comment: A quick question please: Does your suggestion skip the line or the file in case of an error?  The `except` catches the error but does it skip the line only or the whole file?

Comment: yes, you can modify the resulting GeoDataFrame, (delete rows, add rows, modify values)

Comment: There are many examples in GisSE

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. I am asking if the `except` skips the line or the whole file. Thanks

Comment: In this case, the whole file, but you can modify the condition

Comment: Do you have a suggestion please?

Comment: You want to modify the shapefile after it has been read as a GeoDataFrame, so processing is not done in the except clause